# How to dynamically get all nested properties from JSON Array object (example VM data disks) in Azure resource graph

Tags: azure, kql

I am trying to get all data disks attached to a Azure VM from Azure Resource Graph Query. I am able to get specific data disk by specifying the index( for example properties.storageProfile.dataDisks[0].name for first disk) but but how do I get this dynamically when more than 1 data disks are attached.

Comment: resources
| where ['type'] == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend DataDiskName = properties.storageProfile.dataDisks[0].name
| extend DataDiskSizeGB = properties.storageProfile.dataDisks[0].diskSizeGB
| extend DataDiskSizeType = properties.storageProfile.dataDisks[0].managedDisk.storageAccountType

Comment: In the future, when asking a data related question, make sure to provide the required results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Row per disk

```
resources
| where ['type'] == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines' 
| mv-expand with_itemindex = i properties.storageProfile.dataDisks
| extend DataDiskName       = properties_storageProfile_dataDisks.name 
        ,DataDiskSizeGB     = properties_storageProfile_dataDisks.diskSizeGB 
        ,DataDiskSizeType   = properties_storageProfile_dataDisks.managedDisk.storageAccountType
```

2. Column per disk

```
resources
| where ['type'] == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines' 
| mv-expand with_itemindex=i dataDisk = properties.storageProfile.dataDisks
| extend dataDisk = pack_array(dataDisk.name, dataDisk.diskSizeGB, dataDisk.managedDisk.storageAccountType)
| summarize dataDisk0 = anyif(dataDisk, i == 0)
           ,dataDisk1 = anyif(dataDisk, i == 1)
           ,dataDisk2 = anyif(dataDisk, i == 2)
           ,dataDisk3 = anyif(dataDisk, i == 3)
           ,dataDisk4 = anyif(dataDisk, i == 4)
           by id
```

Comment: Thank you David. It gives me output of disks in different rows for same VM. Is it possible to get disks associated with a VM in separate columns?

Comment: See updated answer. P.S. Azure resource graph supports only a very limited subset of KQL.